# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] DTD are not supported by SOAP

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to work a php web service with soap example however i get this error and i don't know what does that mean? Could you help me out? Thanks.

Here is the full error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] DTD are not supported by SOAP in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\istemci.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\istemci.php(3): SoapClient->__call('gonder', Array)
>   #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\istemci.php(3): SoapClient->gonder('mesaj', 'konu', 'kime')
>   #2 {main}
>   thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\istemci.php on line 3

Here is my server.php code:

```
  <?php 
  $istemci=new SoapClient(null,array ('uri'=>'http://ersindogan-testuri','location'=>'http://localhost/test/sunucu.php'));
  var_dump ($istemci->gonder('mesaj','konu','kime'));
  ?>
```

Here is client.php code:

```
     <?php 
         class SMS {
         public function gonder($mesaj,$konu,$kime){
         return 'mesaj gonderildi';    
        } 
      }
     $sunucu=new SoapServer(null,array ('uri'=>'http://ersindogan-testuri'));

     $sunucu->setClass('SMS');

     $sunucu->handle();
```

Comment: try passing individual argument instead of Array

Comment: use `try{} catch()` contsruction to catch `SoapFault` exception and then `var_dump();` it. You will find mpre info on `faultstring` index of output array.

Comment: I added my codes. Could you look at it again, please?

Answer (score 3):

```
1. Check the End point URL, make sure its the right one

2. Check the SOAP header formation. Make sure you have required information, with encoding too .
3. SOAP parameters might be case sensitive
```

Please troubleshoot and reply.

Comment: Thank you. Can you look at my codes that i added up there just now ?